# Can't connect to local MySQL server i am getting error

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have already installed mysql server on my local machine but unfortunately it's not working how can i access please help me step by step thanks.

```
  Not Found
    The requested URL was not found on this server.
    
    Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up different types of applications.

MySQL is a [database application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_data_stream_management_system). It stores data in tables and lets you use [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) (structured query language) to store and retrieve data.

The text you posted seems to be copied from a browser. Browsers are fed HTML (which is text) and can display that graphically. Browsers interact with webservers, like in your case Apache. Webservers host content like webpages, images, CSS files, etc. Sometimes, those webpages are just files containing HTML. And sometimes, those webpages are executable scripts that generate HTML, like PHP scripts.

You are trying to use a browser (for displaying HTML) to interact with MySQL (for storing data). This is not how it works.

Either use a MySQL client application (not a browser) to talk to the database, or use a programming language like PHP to generate HTML that your browser can display.

There is a project called [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/). This is a set of PHP files that talk to your MySQL database, and then generate HTML to be displayed in your browser. In effect: you have a website that you can use to manage your MySQL database.

Install phpMyAdmin using `sudo apt install phpmyadmin` from a terminal, [or by using a GUI tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu). See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04) for detailed instructions on installing phpMyAdmin.